# Deploying Django App stack that's been developed using South?

Tags: django, web-deployment, django-south

So, I've my application stack and I'm ready to deploy it to my webserver.

I'm deploying to a fresh, clean and blank database, so what command to I run?  Do I run ./manage.py syncdb or do I use a South command to setup the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: thank you Craig - wasn't sure I was to use 'syncdb' anymore :)